# Pandas: Can I use the round() method on the mode of a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format

I am trying to format the output of a 'year' which is stored as a float, to be rounded to 0 decimal places, and to remove the dataframe info.

```
# Display earliest, most recent, and most common year of birth
print('Earliest year of birth:')
min_yob = df.birth_year.min()
print(round(min_yob))

print('Max year of birth: ')
max_yob = df.birth_year.max()
print(round(max_yob))

print('Most common year of birth: ')
mod_yob = df.birth_year.mode()
print(round(mod_yob))
```

The output that I get for this is as follows:

```
Earliest year of birth:
1899
Max year of birth: 
2016
Most common year of birth: 
0    1989.0
dtype: float64
```

If I convert mod_yob to an int, it will display correctly, but I'm not sure why round() isn't working here.

```
 Most common year of birth: 
 1989
```

Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a single value in the `Series` is of type float - which it appears is the case in your scenario - then the `mode` function will output float values. Best to ensure that the Series of values are all of type integers *before* the fact.

```
df["birth_year"] = df["birth_year"].astype(int)
```

If you have `NaN`'s present, try this:

```
df["birth_year"] = df["birth_year"].astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
```

Comment: The reason that I've left it as float is that there are lots of NaN values, which from what I understand can't be of type int.   I will try what you've suggested and report back.  Thankyou

Comment: Hi Liz, I've updated the answer for the case of NaNs

Comment: Thanks Andy - that looks like it's fixed the issue for me.  Much appreciated....

Comment: I'm stuck on how to remove the dtype info text (and the zero) - the info I've found so far seems overly complicated....
    `Most common year of birth: `
     `0    1989` 
    `dtype: Int64`

Comment: The output is represented as a DataFrame because you can have multiple results for a single call of `mode` (unlike `max` and `min`). If you know there will only be a single result, you can call `df.birth_year.mode().iloc[0]' to get the first result

Comment: Thanks - that's fixed another problem I was having trouble with. Cheers!